# Bootstrap dropdown menu not working in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a dropdown menu within my Rails application. I've copied the correct code to show a dropdown menu, but when I try to click on the menu it does not show the correct options.

Using bootstrap cdn:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Idealprospects</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Your Prospects</h1>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th class="center">Company</th>
      <th class="center">Name</th>
      <th class="center">Email</th>
      <th class="center">Telephone</th>
      <th class="center">Website</th>
      <th class="center">Action</th>
    </tr>

    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= post.company %></td>
        <td><%= post.contact %></td>
        <td><%= post.email %></td>
        <td><%= post.telephone %></td>
        <td><%= post.website %></td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Action <span class="caret"></span>
               </button>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><%= link_to 'Show', post, class: "btn btn-link" %></li>
              <li><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post), class: "btn btn-link" %>
              <li><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-link" %> </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path, class: "btn btn-link" %>

</div>
```

Comment: The RailsApps project has a nice rails-bootstrap example app that will show you how to integrate Bootstrap with Rails using a gem and the asset pipeline (a recommended practice): https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-bootstrap/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your code I see you have only bootstrap.css included while it requires js also

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

**Dropdowns**

> Toggleable, contextual menu for displaying lists of links. Made
>   interactive with the **dropdown JavaScript** plugin.

Comment: cool so data-toggle="dropdown" is required how would this be implemented using with my rails code bceuase they give me the html code

Comment: hi its ok i added <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>